# How can I convert a mne Info into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, streamlit, mne-python

I'm working with streamlit and EEG data. So I'm using mne library to process the edf files.

The thing is that to visualize into streamlit I would like to convert my data.info into a pandas dataframe.

```
type(data.info) ---> <class 'mne.io.meas_info.Info'>
```

Anyone knows how can I do this?
Thanks!

Comment: Try to ask this in the official [github](https://github.com/mne-tools/mne-python) page.

Answer (score 1):

You likely want to turn the signal data array into a dataframe, not the `.info` attribute, that holds information about channel position, sampling frequency or measurement date. The channel data are stored as a numpy array in `._data` attribute of the Raw object, but the preferred way to access it is using `.get_data()` method.

However, if you just want to turn the channel data to a dataframe - Raw and Epochs objects have [`.to_dataframe()` method](https://mne.tools/stable/generated/mne.io.Raw.html#mne.io.Raw.to_data_frame).

Visualising the EEG signal is also easy with mne-python, you can do `data.plot()` for example. Before visualising the data you may also want to filter the signal, in such case you can use `data.filter()` method (specifying filter edges as arguments).

Comment: This might have something useable in conjunction with that `.to_dataframe()` method: ['Convert group MNE EEG data to pandas DataFrame and compute mean amplitudes over time windows'](https://gist.github.com/aaronjnewman/1a957666ae626e103bce8286ae324001).